# How to write to a input field of type file in a web page programatically from a c# windows app using mshtml?

Tags: c#, mshtml

I have a c# windows app project which has to open IE, navigate to a website, login and then upload a few files.

I used shDocvW and mshtml libraries to do this. I am able to open IE, navigate to the website and login but am not able to upload the files.

I am able to navigate to the website and then add a text value to the input fields(This is an input field of type "text") on the website using -

```
HTMLInputElement txtbox1 =(HTMLInputElement)oDoc.all.item("login", 0);
txtbox1.value = "Login_name";
```

I also was similarly able to even add a text value to the input field of type "password". After I logged in to the website, I have to upload a file.

The problem I am facing is that I am not able to add the path(a string) to the input field of type "file".

I am not able to find any solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried many ways to do this but it was not possible because IE8 made the Value property of  read-only for security reasons.

Well, I did find a work around. It is very simple but the use of `SendKeys` is not always considered the best programming solution. But, it does the job.

```
oBrowser.Navigate("http://www.some-url.com", ref oNull, ref oNull, ref oNull, ref oNull);        

while (oBrowser.Busy)   
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
}

//Locate the Input element of type="file"
HTMLInputElement file_1 = (HTMLInputElement)oDoc.all.item("file_1", 0);
file_1.select();        

SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");   //Navigate to the Browse button
SendKeys.Send(" ");       //Click on the browse button

SendKeys.Send(@"c:\Test.txt");         //File Path
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

This code can be bettered by checking for the active window and perhaps setting the correct one before every `SendKeys` command. This can be done by using the `FindWindow()` and `FindWindowEx()` of `user32.dll`. These methods in the windows API are used to find the active window and the child windows.

Comment: One problem, even when I close all the windows on my machine,
The code above does not give actual path to the browse pop-up window.
It omits some character from the beginning.

Like for you examples it might enter only "\Test.txt" and ignore "c:" part.

Is it all because internally for a sec some other window gets active?

Answer (score 2):

Does your implementation have to involve using IE? This may be simpler using the `WebClient` class to upload the file using a POST request, but this does depend on if the form provides any other post actions with the upload. If not, you can use `WebClient.UploadFile`.

If you need to upload multiple POST values for this form (i.e. new file name?), have a look here: [WebClient.UploadFile and WebClient.UploadValues in the same call](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ncl/thread/34fa35eb-38af-4505-967e-306ad6068831)